# Update MySQL new IPv6 column with existing IPv4 column data

Tags: mysql, ipv6, ipv4

I have the following two columns in a MySQL database table named "ip_test":

- `ipv4` as `INT(11)` (example value for 127.0.0.1: `2130706433`).
- `ipv6` as `VARBINARY` (example value for 127.0.0.1: `0xFE800000000000000202B3FFFE1E8329`).

What is the simplest manner to effectively convert the data (for a visual demonstration of the idea: `UPDATE ip_test SET ipv6=ipv4;`) though properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My goal was to avoid any server side scripting and to achieve this purely in MySQL. This seems correct from my initial tests:

```
UPDATE ip_test SET ipv6 = INET6_ATON(INET_NTOA(ipv4));
```